# Java Reentrant lock dead lock

Tags: java, concurrency, reentrantlock

Why java reentrant lock does not cause dead lock?

I was studying Reentrant lock, and did realize that a thread failed to try acquire will be placed in a sync queue, and before it parks, it set its prev node's waitStatus to SIGNAL, and recheck if the prev node has set its stat to 0, if not, it might be sure that the prev node has not unparked it, because it has not cleared the SIGNAL state, so it parks. But what if the interval between
shoudParkAFterFailedAcquire and parkAndCheckInterrrupt takes, say 1 second or 1 minute long,
so unpark arrives first before parking. Would this cause a deadlock?
[image]

Comment: Deadlock is where you have two or more threads that own locks and each thread is trying to acquire the other's locks. The situation you describe would not be a deadlock. Don't misuse standard terminology.

Comment: OK, thanks, but what should I call this, maybe, never-waken-up parking?

Comment: Not sure actually. Bug?

Comment: I didn't run into this but, I was just wondering why this would not happen.

Comment: Any time the outcome of a program depends on how the execution of different threads is interleaved, you can call that a "race condition." Some people prefer to say "data race" if any of the possible outcomes is acceptable, and they only say "race condition" if one or more of the possible outcomes is bad/wrong.

Answer (score 4):

`park` and `unpark` don't work like you seem to think they do.  They are based on a permit-like system:

- When a thread is unparked, it is granted a "permit" if it doesn't already have one.
- When a thread calls `park`, it blocks until it has a permit and the permit is revoked.  If it already has a permit when `park` is called, then it doesn't block at all.

So it doesn't matter if it takes a minute or more for `acquireQueued` to get to the `park`, because the preceding call to `unpark` has already provided the thread with a permit.  The permit will be revoked without blocking.

Comment: Thanks, I rechecked the docs,  it does work this way!